# how to create esb proxy with basic authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, wso2-esb

I want to expose a wso2esb proxy service using basic authentication. When securing a service on the ESB, I see the possibility to secure it using ws-security headers, but some of our clients do not support that.
Is it possible to configure ESB to accept:

- basic authentication
- only check on ldap account (username/password) and not roles - so only authentication, not authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new User Store configured for LDAP. Then select your service in the GUI and click the "Unsecured" link which will take you through the security setup. You want the "UsernameToken" scenario for basic authentication.

Comment: Thanks - what for me was unclear, is that basic authentication came along with the usernametoken scenario.